# Keeping only certain parts of a multiline text box

Tags: vb.net

net 2.0 program and in it I have a multi line text box.
For one of my operations I only need to retrieve certain parts of the txt box
for instance
[image: samplecode]

I need to retrieve the following

- 01-11-2013 15-18-12 -
- Computer: 740TMP
- 01-11-2013 15-18-13 -
- Computer: 740TMP

The text box can have just 1 entry or 30 entry. I know I can truncate the lines but then I would still have extra lines in the final results.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes, parse the string and get the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `List(Of String)` to store the result with your desired lines. Then use a loop to iterate all lines in the TextBox and take what you need.

For example:

```
Dim desiredLines As New List(Of String)()
Dim allLInes As String() = textBox1.Lines
Dim datePattern As String = "dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss"

For i As Integer = 0 To allLInes.Length - 1
    Dim line As String = allLInes(i).Trim()
    Dim dt As Date 
    If line.Length >= datePattern.Length AndAlso _
        Date.TryParseExact(line.Substring(0, datePattern.Length), datePattern, Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
        desiredLines.Add(dt.ToString(datePattern))
    ElseIf line.StartsWith("Computer:") Then
        desiredLines.Add(line.Split("-"c)(0).TrimEnd())
    End If
Next
```